# Загрузить изображение в папку Resources программно через форму WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, resources

Можно ли программно добавить изображение в папку Resources проекта через форму WPF? Если это можно сделать, то как?
Если где-то уже есть ответы по теме подскажите, плиз...

Comment: Ваше приложение будет скорее всего установлено в C:\Program Files, в защищённый от записи каталог. Записать туда файл не получится. Нужные файлы программа должна складывать в %APPDATA%\<имя вашей программы>.

Comment: VladD, папка Resources находится в папке с проектом WPF на диске D. Мне нужно, чтобы изображение добавлялось в ресурсы проекта. Это можно делать перетаскиванием изображений в проект, но изображений много, поэтому я хочу реализовать это программно через форму WPF.

Comment: Ресурсы - это часть приложения, которые запаковываются во время компиляции в .exe/.dll/.res файл. Вы не должны хотеть туда что либо добавлять, не должны хотеть там что либо изменять, ибо их цель - это просто хранить нужное (иконки, шрифты, переводы, и прочее). Если вам надо динамически подгружать изображения из папки, то так и делайте, берете путь, берете от туда файлы, делаете с ними что угодно.

Comment: Это может иметь смысл, если вы пишете вспомогательную утилиту для разработки. Но на машине клиента программа обязана уметь работать из защищённого от записи каталога. Если вы видите программу, которая настаивает, чтобы её устанавливали в корень диска C — её писали неумелые программисты.